# object or container used to store sensitive information

Tags: java

This is asked in one of my interviews:

```
In Java what object or container is used to store sensitive information?
```

When I searched I got this link [Why is char[] preferred over String for passwords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881291/why-is-char-preferred-over-string-for-passwords)

So is character array is the right answer to this question?

Comment: The question doesn't make a lot of sense.  What do they mean by "container", "store" and "sensitive".   A `char[]` is the correct answer in some cases, not others.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we can't know what the interviewers were hoping to hear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that the interviewer was after `KeyStore`, but a more general answer would be `SealedObject`.

The answer about `char` only applies as against `String`, because you can wipe a `char` but not a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to hazard a guess, it would likely be the [`KeyStore`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html) class.  If you do anything with a signed web certificate (like serve HTTPS in Spring Boot or use Tomcat to serve HTTPS traffic), or need to have some encrypted credentials in-situ in your application, this is the class one *typically* uses.

Character arrays are great in that they're not as vulnerable to pre-garbage collection attacks, but there's no inherent *encryption* or security to those by default.

Comment: I see that `KeyStore` is used to store the SSL ceritificates, is there a way to store for example an employee credit card details securely with this class, I tried to find a example but every I see only example related to certitifcates.

Comment: No it isn't. It is only usable for keys or certificates. Not arbitrary data.

Answer (score -2):

Unfortunately, your question ultimately lacks both clarity and context for the question that'd been asked of you, but I'll make the default assumption and go with "a private member" as the most likely desired answer. So: no, I suspect answering with "a character array" may have even raised an eyebrow IF you did not follow up with the specifically recommended use case for char[]s. That use case only has to do with explicitly obfuscating data in memory *when you are done with that value* and no other inherent protections while you need the value in memory.

Comment: Considering that `private` is a keyword, and there's no inherent encryption or protection around an instance, I'm going to have to **categorically** disagree with you here...

Comment: I completely understand that disagreement, but wanted to point out that my answer was also "a hazard at a guess". There's no real indication of what "sensitive" means, nor at what level it is being hidden from something. I would probably strive for an answer similar to yours (if I'd known a common Java class for it, anyway) when interviewing for a development leadership position at a financial institution. I was clearly thinking more along the lines of an entry level position. Perhaps I'd not be qualified for either! LOL. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: The question asks for what "object or container". The keyword `private` has nothing to do with that.