# Can we use KeyStore to store sensitive data

Tags: java, security

This is in addition to my previous question answered by Makoto [object or container used to store sensitive information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48237599/object-or-container-used-to-store-sensitive-information?noredirect=1#comment83458701_48237599)

After reading some articles, I see that in Java we can use [KeyStore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html) to store web certificates, but can I use this object to store application-specific data for example Bank details, Credit card information, etc? I have not seen any examples in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can only store keys and certificates in a keystore.

Comment: Thank you, is there any other object in Java which is designed to store sensitive information.

Comment: There is `SealedObject`, which you can serialize if your data is `Serializable`.

Comment: You can use anything to store sensitive data as long as data is encrypted and you are the only one who has access to the key.